# What noun describes the property of banknotes as a store of value and a medium of exchange rather than just a store of value?

Tags: single-word-requests

Stocks, bonds, houses, and certificates of deposits (CDs) function as stores of value but not as mediums of exchange. It is not possible to steal houses, because houses are registered in people's names. In contrast, banknotes function both as a store of value and as a medium of exchange. It is possible to steal banknotes. If someone steals a $10 note from me, and I don't know who the thief is, I won't be able to recover the stolen $10 note.

What word describes this difference between banknotes and houses? I have seen this word before, but I cannot remember it. It is a noun (ending in -ity).

Comment: You may be thinking of *liquidity*, but liquidity is about the ease with which something can be exchanged, and not about its value. Cash is the most liquid asset, but stocks, bonds and other securities are also relatively liquid compared to real estate or private equity, for example. Something which holds a fixed value and is used for exchange is essentially the definition of *currency*.

Comment: Currency? Oh no, that doesn't end in "-ity"   (cross-posted)

Comment: @choster, currency only holds a "fixed value" in its own terms. The goods and services which it can claim is not fixed.

Comment: I'm not sure this question is well-founded. The distinction is obviously between registered transactions (as nowadays with houses) and bearer instruments (as with cash). But practically speaking, the person *in possession* (of houses or cash) is always by default presumed to be the owner until shown otherwise, and it is perfectly possible to be convicted of stealing cash. The reason houses can usually be recovered and banknotes potentially cannot, is simply because you can't feasibly move the house from its location - so there is never an issue of ascertaining the property in question.

Comment: [***Fungibility***](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fungible) is an attribute that applies to *banknotes*, but not *houses*. If you lend someone a dollar bill, you don't care if you're repaid with a different actual banknote. But if you lent someone your *house*, you probably wouldn't be expecting to get back a "similar" house.

Comment: Yeah, I'm vaguely recalling an "-ity" term too, but I can't think of it just now.  (I don't see it in any of the so-far-mentioned terms.)

Comment: As a side note, I have heard of people's houses being stolen via identity theft. The thief poses as the homeowner and transfers the title to another person. I don't mean to muddy the waters, but it can happen.

Comment: They’re bearer instruments.

Comment: You may be thinking of the term negotiability. A negotiable instrument is an unconditional promise to pay a sum certain in money at a determinable future date.

Comment: @Xanne The most common negotiable instrument in the U.S. is an order to pay a sum certain at sight. If such a negotiable instrument is drawn on a bank, it is called a "check." You were on the money with "bearer instrument." But negotiable instruments need not be bearer instruments. A check payable to you is not a bearer instrument unless you endorse it without restriction. That is why you endorse a check "for deposit only," to keep it from becoming bearer paper. In other words, negotiability is a broader concept than what the OP is after.

Comment: A banknote is a token of value and a medium of exchange, the other examples are stores of value.

Answer (score 2):

Is **liquidity** the word you are looking for?
[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/liquidity) has

> **liquidity**
> NOUN
>
> **1** Finance
> The availability of liquid assets to a market or company.
>
> **1.1** Liquid assets; cash.
> *a firm may be unable to pay unless it has spare liquidity*

A banknote is classed as a **liquid asset** whereas my house is not. It is an asset, but has no **liquidity**.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you might be looking for the word *fungibility*. [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fungibility) describes it as

> the property of a good or a commodity whose individual units are essentially interchangeable, and each of its parts is indistinguishable from another part.

That makes it correspond to banknotes of a given value, which *a priori* are all interchangeable, but excludes things like houses (and apparently bitcoin, because bitcoin identifiers tied to  fraudulent transactions can be blocked [[source (in French)]](http://gdt.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8425962)).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what word you are looking forward because I do not think a word exists that exactly captures the distinction that you are trying to capture. The closest I can come are some related terms of art in U.S. commercial law, namely 'bearer document," "bearer instrument," "bearer paper," and "bearer security." (Although U.S. commercial law derives from the law merchant and English common law, I have no clue whether other jurisdictions have the same vocabulary).

Here is an abbreviation of Black's Law Dictionary's definition of bearer instrument: it is an "instrument ... which does not purport to designate a specific payee." A banknote is a both a "bearer instrument" and "bearer paper": the bank that issued it is released from liability by paying the person with physical possession of the note. (I leave out of consideration special circumstances such as the bank having knowledge that the instrument was stolen.)

Of course, banknotes in the general sense have not existed in the U.S. for decades: state-chartered banks were effectively prohibited from issuing them in, if I remember correctly, 1863 though national banks continued to issue them for about seventy more years. Technically, the only banknotes still issued in the U.S. are Federal Reserve Notes, i.e, currency.

Comment: not sure.. negotiability?

Comment: @Narasimham  Bearer instruments are negotiable instruments, but not all negotiable instruments are bearer instruments. So "negotiability" may be the word the OP is looking for, but that word does not describe the concept that the OP specified.

Comment: thanks. yes, so said.. not sure